# in mongodb,i have two collection user and adress i want to get all the users who lives for example in the same city

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql

hi please help I'm new in MongoDB, I have two collection user and address I want to get all the users who live for example in the same city

Mongoose schemes:

```
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', {
    fname: String,
    mname: String,
    lname: String,
    address: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Address'}
});


var Address = mongoose.model('Address', {
    houseNum: String,
    street: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.Person.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Address",
      localField: "address",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $first: "$docs.city"
      },
      person_ids: {
        $push: "$_id"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WxMQvJPJwdj)